# How to view frames by placing the cursor in Html5 Video Player?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, frame, video-player

Is this Viewing Frames just by placing cursor in Video player is possible in Html5 Video player ? ( just like in youtube )
How can i do that ?
[image: Poster frame]

Answer (score 0):

No, HTML5 Video player does not support this. You have to generate video thumbnail images then you have to use that. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771059/dynamic-video-thumbnail-on-hover) answer.