# What is this technique called using html5 video?

Tags: javascript

I want to make preview images while playing some videos like Youtube's:

[image: 1]

I don't know what is it called and I have tried to search with the keyword: *javascript video preview*, then I get this post: [How can I set preview of video file, selecting from input type='file'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035721/how-can-i-set-preview-of-video-file-selecting-from-input-type-file)
. But it's different.

Can you tell me how to do that or what is the name of the technique? Thank you!

Comment: I guess it's generally called [*thumbnail seeking*](https://www.google.com/search?q=video+thumbnail+seeking).

Comment: This feature [doesn't seem to be public](https://github.com/h5p/h5p-moodle-plugin/issues/58#issuecomment-219857798) even in YouTube SDK but, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771059/dynamic-video-thumbnail-on-hover) is a discussion on working out the feature on SO.